# How to remove files with history from git?

Tags: git

I have a project, which I'd like to opensource. 90% of the project can be safely opensourced, but there are two subprojects, which contains information potentially sensitive to my previous employers. I may delete them, commit and push, but the history will still contain those two projects, so someone determined enough can quite easily restore them.

Is there a way to permanently remove files from git along with their complete history?